# Is there a C# counterpart to this javascript trick for avoiding too much recursion

Tags: c#, knockout.js

In javascript it is possible to prevent a "too much recursion" error, when a method is calling itself, by wrapping the recursive call in `setTimeout`.  For example, this eventhandler adds one item at a time to a knockout observable array, using `array.shift()` and recursion instead of a loop:

```
$(document).on("AddPizzaFan", function (event, data, results) {

    var item = data.shift();
    var fan =   new PizzaFan(

                     item['firstname'],
                     item['lastname'],
                     item['favoritePizzaTopping']

        )
    myObservableArray.push(fan);
    if (data.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () { $(document).trigger("AddPizzaFan", [data, myObservableArray]); }, 1);
    }

});
```

This approach allows a UI component bound to the KO observable to be updated one data row at a time, making the UI seem fast and responsive even when `data` contains thousands of rows and might otherwise require 5 or 10 or even 60 seconds or more to appear if the `data` array was simply fed all at once to the UI. When the array is fed to the UI in many small bits, the user starts to see data on the screen right away. (FWIW, the actual application is a text corpora search where many paragraphs of text are returned which contain the user's search term or search phrase.)

Can something comparable to this be done with a `Stack` and async `await` in C# ?  Reading [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808166/recursion-and-the-await-async-keywords), it seems that it can't, at least not easily. If it is possible to do something similar in C#, how is it accomplished?

Comment: What kind of UI are you using? Windows Forms? Windows Presentation Foundation?

Comment: You don't need to rely on JavaScript tricks. c# has lots of capabilities to deal with threads and asynchronous programming. Just forget those tricks an embrace c# approach

Comment: @JesúsLópez: That is *exactly* my question. What are the counterpart C# approaches.

Comment: @JesúsLópez: My UI is Blazor, where I am an utter newb.

Comment: Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: The best solution for this problem is data virtualization. I'm not sure what kind of virtualization support Blazor controls currently have.

Comment: @JesúsLópez: At this point it is Blazor-Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code could be implemented in c# as follow:

Recursive Implementation:

```
async Task RecursiveTask(Stack<object> data, Queue<object> myObservableArray)
{
    if (data.Count > 0)
    {
        myObservableArray.Enqueue(data.Pop()); // or any other logic
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        await RecursiveTask(data, myObservableArray);
    }
}
```

Non-recursive Implementation (**Recommended**):

```
async Task RecursiveTask(Stack<object> data, Queue<object> myObservableArray)
{
    while (data.Count > 0)
    {
        myObservableArray.Enqueue(data.Pop()); // or any other logic
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: only that recursion is not necessary at all

Comment: @JesúsLópez : You're right. I try to show Tim `recursive version` I'll update my answer with non recursive version too, thanks for your point